# How can the universe be dodecahedron-shaped?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, observable-universe

[Physicsworld](https://physicsworld.com/a/is-the-universe-a-dodecahedron/) references [*"Dodecahedral space topology as an explanation for weak wide-angle temperature correlations in the cosmic microwave background"*](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0310253) by J.-P. Luminet et al., published in Nature (Nature 425 (2003) 593).

They claim that a universe with the same shape as the twelve-sided polygon can explain measurements of the cosmic microwave background.

How could this be true? I thought the universe's shape is spherically symmetric. Does this mean the universe has sharp edges (like a dodecahedron)?! Doesn't this mean that the universe prefers some directions to the others?

Comment: As always, the question closed before I had the time to give my answer. See http://www.ic.uff.br/~aconci/poincare.pdf http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Cosmic_Topology https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem for the science. This is a real topic with peer reviewed publications.

Comment: @JonCuster - Note that there are publications on empirical searches for nontrivial finite constant curvature spaces from the Planck Collaboration https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01593 beside a big theory literature. Just because the impetus of a question comes from some random site does not mean the question is bad - indeed, the anisotropy issue is taken seriously in cosmology.

Comment: @AndersSandberg unfortunately none of your links actually refer to peer-reviewed work.  I for one am quite curious...  maybe there’s a review article you can point to?

Comment: This question needs to be expanded so people don’t have to read an article to u der stand it.

Comment: @AndersSandberg The question is now reopened. I have edited in a reference to a peer-reviewed paper published in a reputable journal. Please consider more often submitting an edit yourself if you'd like to answer a question suffering from poor demonstration that it is mainstream.

Comment: @AndersSandberg when you are interested to answer a question but suspect closure ahead,write a place holding answer. I sometimes write "place holder , working on answer,  before closure. " You can then access and edit after closure

Comment: @annav That technique is okay within some limits. We had a user a few years ago who interpreted advice like that by writing and deleting the text "placeholder answer" on several iffy questions, then editing and un-deleting as a way to circumvent the community's close decision. We prefer that, in general, such "placeholder" answers *actually answer* the question at all stages of their existence, even if their first version answers in an incomplete way. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The universe is not believed to have a boundary. But [the global topology of space](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Cosmic_Topology) does not have to be a 3-sphere $S^3$ (for constant positive curvature), infinite flat space $R^3$ (for zero curvature) or a 3D hyperbolic pseudosphere $H^3$ (for negative curvature). General relativity only describes the *local* structure and curvature, not the *global* topology.

[The Killing–Hopf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem) (all complete connected Riemannian manifolds of constant curvature are isometric to a quotient of a sphere, Euclidean space, or hyperbolic space by a group acting freely and properly discontinuously) indicates that for constant curvature spaces various topologies are possible. These correspond to taking a chunk of one of the "default" spaces mentioned above and identifying the faces so that going through one of them means one enters the volume from one of the other faces. The most obvious is taking a box of flat space and identifying opposite faces so it acts as a 3-torus.

It is possible to construct several nontrivial finite volume zero or positively curved spaces (and even more for negative curvature, where there might be an infinite number of possibilities).  [The Poincaré Dodecahedral Space, formed by identifying opposite faces of a regular dodecahedron after a 36 degree rotation, has been discussed as a cosmological model](http://www.ic.uff.br/~aconci/poincare.pdf). This is the one the question dealt with. The reason for the shape is that it corresponds to a particular symmetry group of the sphere, the extended icosahedron group. While [the space can be defined in many ways](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Poincar%C3%A9's_homology_sphere), they are all equivalent (and different from the spaces when one uses a different group).

This kind of space is in one sense spherically symmetric: the curvature is constant. But all directions are not the same, so it is not quite isotropic. There are no sharp edges, since the joining up is smooth (even in the "corners"). Most importantly, it would act as a "hall of mirrors" where distant objects would be repeated in some pattern if their light has reached us. This allows for searching for the topology by looking at correlations in the cosmic microwave background along circles on the sky (their sizes are set by the size of the space and its topology).

There is currently no evidence for a nontrivial topology. [WMAP placed a limit of 25.6  giga parsec on the cell size](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.92.201302), [even for very general topologies](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.2939). [The Planck collaboration](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5086) placed limits on the radius $R_i$ of the largest inscribed sphere in the topological domain compared to the co-moving distance to the last surface of scattering $\chi\approx 14.0$ Gpc. They found that for a flat universe, $R_i>0.92\chi$ for the 3-torus, $R_i>0.71$ for the prism, and $R_i>0.5\chi$ for the slab, while in a positively curved universe $R_i>1.03\chi$ for the dodecahedral space, $R_i>1.0\chi$ for the truncated cube, and $R_i>0.89\chi$ for the octahedral space. For other considered topologies $R_i>0.94\chi$ at the 99% confidence level.

Comment: The link http://www.ic.uff.br/~aconci/poincare.pdf is to a Scientific American article on the poincare conjecture. From the link text it seems that it should have pointed to an article on PDS instead?

Answer (score 2):

If you read [the abstract](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0310253) of the article given in the comments you will see that there does exist an not explainable with a spherical model angular distribution:

> Temperature correlations across the microwave sky match expectations on scales narrower than 60∘, yet vanish on scales wider than 60∘.

It is this anisotropy modeled with a dodecahedron. After all crystals exist in nature, no? of all types . There are no sharp corners, but angular distributions in the xrays of crystals that define the faces of the geometrical model needed.

Something analogous is postulated to explain the observations.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the phrase "there does exist an un explainable...". Is  there a typo? Is the "un" supposed to be "universe"?

Comment: it is meant to be "not explainable", but it rejected one word "unexplainable"  thanks, I will correct